# How to Hide any page extension like (.aspx and .asp and .php and .html) in asp.net IIS7

Tags: asp.net, url, rewriting

I have a requirement to hide any type of page extension in my site which                     have hosted 100 more page asp,html and aspx pages.
     I want to hide all type page extension . I use following code which only works for                   .aspx. not work on .html & .asp page extension

```
<rule name="RemoveASPX" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)\.aspx" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="AddASPX" enabled="true">
      <match url=".*" negate="false" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="(.*)\.(.*)" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}.aspx" />
    </rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<match url="(.*)\.(aspx|php|html)" />

<action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}.{R:1}" />
```

You can change regex of the match element so it matches on the other extensions.

Comment: What happend when i try to finding a page which is .asp extension . it show me 404 error . and added  .aspx extenstion not .asp extenstion

Answer (score 0):

You can (and should) use the routing mechanism provided by Asp.NET, in your specific case the `MapPageRoute` method as described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd329551%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

What you see about aspx pages can be applied to other kind of pages too, like plain html or old asp.